# drawText() on a QImage crashes program

Tags: qt, qimage

I have an image in uint8_t buffer and I am trying to use QImage as a wrapper to write text on the image.  I have used drawLine() with no issues, but drawText() crashes the program.  The below code is part of a boost thread in which I want to write text unto each image as it iterates through the function.  Are there any bugs in Qt I am unaware of?

```
uint8_t *frameBuffer; // this contains image pixels
QImage img(frameBuffer, sizeX, m_sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB888);

QPainter p(&img);

p.setPen(QPen(Qt::green));
p.setFont(QFont("Times", 10, QFont::Bold));
p.drawLine(img.rect().bottomLeft().x(), img.rect().bottomLeft().y()-10,
           img.rect().bottomRight().x(), img.rect().bottomRight().y()-10);  //works!

p.drawText(img.rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Help");  //crashes program
```

Comment: Youu have checked that framebuffer is valid and big enough?

Comment: Yes I have.  When I comment out the drawText line, the drawline command works as expected.

Comment: 1, Is this part of a full Qt app? do you have a QApplication at the start?   2, do you call p.end(), it might actually be crashing when something goes out of scope and the error just points at the last op.

Comment: It was a QCoreApplication (I had no GUI).  Changing it to QApplication did the trick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My project was set to a QCoreApplication (I had no GUI).  Changing it to QApplication did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess... (I've never seen this error before, but have had other font issues on threads.)

Font rendering on background threads can be a little flaky in Qt, depending on how it was compiled. Check the value of [QFontDatabase::supportsThreadedFontRendering](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html#supportsThreadedFontRendering) on your system.

Note the documentation:

> Returns true if font rendering is supported outside the GUI thread,
>   false otherwise. In other words, a return value of false means that
>   all QPainter::drawText() calls outside the GUI thread will not produce
>   readable output.

Comment: I have a single thread and I got that error, so which thread would not be a problem in my situation...